# Is it possible to use a German dictionary in qdap check_spelling_interactive?

Tags: r, dictionary, qdap

I'm analyzing German comments of an app and I want to use `check_spelling_interactive` of the `qdap` package.

Is it possible to use a German dictionary instead of the `qdap` dictionary?

Comment: I believe so.  Try it but you'd need your own dictionary which in this case is just a vector of possible words.  Hunspell package may be another great choice here.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I tried out Hunspell. It works with a german dictionary.